# Unable to change Statusbar color in Android using IONIC 5

Tags: android, ionic-framework, colors, statusbar, ionic5

My app is in IONIC 5 and I am using the following code to change the status bar color in the `app.component.ts file`.

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    ...
    private statusBar: StatusBar
    ...
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
      ...
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
      ...
  }
}
```

It seems IOS is automatically changing the Statusbar color matching with the toolbar even if I am not changing it in the code but for Android, the Statusbar color is always black and not changing.

Comment: please share your package.json

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you are in a Capacitor on ionic Native project. You have two options:

Op 1. Run npm install for using cordova package: `npm install cordova-plugin-statusbar`, then run `ionic build --prod` and `npx cap sync android`. [check the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar) for outofdate cordova/capacitor instructions.

Here you have a sample, statusbar working with OnInit and platform ready, you can choose.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   // Dont mix, choose OnInit or platform ready
   //this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {  
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByName("yellow");
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Op 2. Capacitor without cordova as capacitor already gives you StatusBar object
[Use Capacitor Core Status Bar](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar):

```
import {
  Plugins,
  StatusBarStyle,
} from '@capacitor/core';

const { StatusBar } = Plugins;

export class StatusBarExample {
  isStatusBarLight = true

  changeStatusBar() {
    StatusBar.setStyle({
      style: this.isStatusBarLight ? StatusBarStyle.Dark : StatusBarStyle.Light
    });
    this.isStatusBarLight = !this.isStatusBarLight;

    // Display content under transparent status bar (Android only)
    StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({
      overlay: true
    });
    
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({color:"#215E96"})

  }

  hideStatusBar() {
    StatusBar.hide();
  }

  showStatusBar() {
    StatusBar.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me.

Im not using:

```
this.statusBar.styleDefault();
```

Only the next code in app.component.ts file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
ngOnInit() {
    this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
  }
}
```